# Where am i going wrong with using promise inside class?

Tags: javascript, node.js, javascript-objects

i am using the class as follows

```
var user_class = function (body) {
    this.body = body;
};

user_class.prototype.login = function () {
    var that = this;
    return new Promise((fullfill,reject)=>{
        that.find_by_username()
            .then(that.user_exists)
            .then(that.check_credentials)
            .then(that.generate_token)
            .then(fullfill)
            .catch(reject);
    });
};

user_class.prototype.find_by_username = function () {
    var that = this;
    return new Promise((fullfill,reject)=>{
        user_model
            .find({username: that.body.username})
            .then((user)=>{
                that.user = user;
            })
            .then(fullfill)
            .catch(reject);
    });
};

user_class.prototype.user_exists = function () {
    var that = this;
    return new Promise((fullfill,reject)=>{
        console.log(that.user);
        if(that.user !== undefined) {
            fullfill();
        }else{
            reject(new Error('null user'));
        }
    });
};
```

The problem is when i call the `login` method, the `find_by_username` function works just fine and the user us set properly which i validated from `console.log` on `that.user` . but the `user_exits` method throws error which means it is finding that the `user` is set to undefined. I already refered to `this` to `that` and still not working.

Can someone please explain what is wrong with my logic and why the user is not being set to object ?

Comment: That is not necessary here. And youre loosing context in the thens. Do .then(....bind(that))

Comment: could you just add a sample example for me . this is my first time using promise with class. I think i am guessing you mean inside the signup function method chain rt?

Comment: never mind got it working.. post an answer if you want :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the loose of context but not like you think. Its not because *this* is overriden through binding, but because you loose context while passing functions:

```
user_class.prototype.login = function () {
  return new Promise((fullfill,reject)=>{
    this.find_by_username()
        .then(this.user_exists.bind(this))
        .then(this.check_credentials.bind(this))
        .then(this.generate_toke.bind(this))
        .then(fullfill)
        .catch(reject);
});
};
```